# How can I put a condition to show a CMS page only for logged in member in Magento?

Tags: magento

How can I put a condition to differentiate a login in user or a guest user so that I can show different pages to them?

Any suggestions?

Comment: i have one cms page link of magento on which i want to show separate text for a logged in user and separate for a guest user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi open "app\design\frontend\default[Your Theme]\template\page\page.phtml" and put this condition

```
    $login = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn(); //Check if User is Logged In
 if(!$login)
 {
 $msg = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Please Sign in / Register first to access this page.'));
 header('Location: '. Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
 exit;
 }
```

for further you can check "http://tinajam.wordpress.com/".